# Prove that a relation isn't transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
M_{R}=
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{eqnarray*}
Where $M_{R}$ is the relation matrix for a relation $R$. Is $R$ reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric or transitive?

---

I find that is Symmetric but isn't reflexive and antisymmetric, To verify if $M_{R}$ is transitive. I compute the Boolean product
\begin{eqnarray}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix} 
  \odot
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}  
\end{eqnarray}
That means that $M_{R}\odot M_{R}\neq M_{R}$, So $M_{R}$ isn't transitive. This is correct?

Comment: PS: The relation **is** symmetric.   $\forall i{\in}\{1,2,3\}~\forall j{\in}\{1,2,3\}~\big(\mathrm M_{R(i,j)}=\mathrm M_{R(j,i)}\big)$

Comment: Oh.. I'm wrong. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the case.

As evidence: $\mathrm M_{R(3,2)}\,{=}\,1$ and $\mathrm M_{R(2,3)}\,{=}\,1$ but $\mathrm M_{R(3,3)}\,{=}\,0$ .